# What should I do to make my app run smoother?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have created image app in android studio. There are almost 75 images in drawable resources in android studio.
But as the image size is big, the app crashes  or images scroll very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loading the image in application use Glide Image loading library

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

It will load image asynchronously and efficient way

After if problem persist review ur code and check in android profiler

This sample way how to load images in image view and for example on Glide search in google

```
 GlideApp.with(this).load("url").into(imageView);
```